# Core Data storedata file takes up too much space

Tags: cocoa, core-data, storage

I have only one entity, which has two attributes: an **NSString** attribute and a transformable attribute for **image** storage.

When I creat six entities with six images whose sizes are about **1.7MB**, the storedata file now takes up **19.6MB** space using NSBinaryStoreType or NSSQLiteStoreType.

That is unacceptable, am I going wrong with Core Data? Or just this is natural of Core Data? How can I reduce the storedata file size? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the images in external files, then store the path to them as a string in Core Data.

Comment: I'm using the "allow external storage" option for the binary data, but a 3000 x 2000 image which only takes 1.5MB in iPhone Photo Library still takes 15MB - any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS Lion, managed objects can store their attributes externally. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: But the space which core data takes up is still very large. I found out once the image being transformed to binary data, it got blow up.

Comment: @LiFumin have you figured out why? Any solution to that? a 3000 x 2000 image which only takes 1.5MB in iPhone Photo Library still takes 15MB

Comment: @hyouuu I haven't verified this, but I'm guessing that core data will store the images as TIFF data which are bigger than JPEG. You could override the setter and getter and store it as JPEG data (see NSBitmapImageRep). But it's easier using Jeff Kelleys answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was already using external storage and it still took lots of space. Turns out that if I store in JPG with 0.99 compression rate it drastically reduce the size. Still can't figure out why the iOS Photo Gallery PNGs only takes 1MB for the full sized image though...

Comment: @hyouuu It's been 4 years, I can't remember my final solution if there is any. Sorry. You can take Jeff Kelley's answer as a solution, though.